# Can't Export signed/unsigned applicationpackage

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-build

I have built an Android app which I now want to pack as an APK. In the app I have used the Google-play service library. When I try to pack it, I get error message on these lines ... What to do?

```
<!-- Title of confirmation dialog informing the user that a network error occurred. [CHAR LIMIT=40] -->
<string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_title">Network Error</string>

<!-- Message in confirmation dialog informing the user that a network error occurred. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_text">A data connection is required to connect to Google Play services.</string>

<!-- Title of confirmation dialog informing the user that they provided an invalid account. [CHAR LIMIT=40] -->
<string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title">Invalid Account</string>

<!-- Message in confirmation dialog informing the user that they provided an invalid account. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text">The specified account does not exist on this device. Please choose a different account.</string>

   <!-- Message in confirmation dialog informing user that date on the device is not correct,
    causing certificate checks to fail. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_date_text">The date on the device appears to be incorrect. Please check the date on the device.</string>
```

ERROR

```
    "common_google_play_services_network_error_title" is not translated in be

Issue: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
Id: MissingTranslation

If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared in one language should also be translated in all other languages.

If the string should not be translated, you can add the attribute translatable="false" on the <string> element, or you can define all your non-translatable strings in a resource file called donottranslate.xml. Or, you can ignore the issue with a tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" attribute.

By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide a subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language strings. You can require all regions to provide a full translation by setting the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

You can tell lint (and other tools) which language is the default language in your res/values/ folder by specifying tools:locale="languageCode" for the root <resources> element in your resource file. (The tools prefix refers to the namespace declaration http://schemas.android.com/tools.)

[]
```

Comment: Read the lint error message. It gives you many good options.

Answer (score 1):

This not fatal error really. You should fix it anyway prior releasing, but for you I'd just disable `Lint` from being invoked automatically on export in `Settings` -> `Android` -> `Lint Error Checking`.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you have some strings in a different folder. Any string in your strings.xml in a values-xx folder has to.be placed in the values folder (default folder) aswell in order to export your app.